# Folium: how to create some leeway for displayed placemarkers

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, folium

The following simple code creates three placemarks, computes the proper NE and SW bounding box and uses folium.Map.fit_bounds to set the proper zoom level to display them on the map.

What I'd like to achieve if possible is to have some more space around the placemarks, just like the user would have clicked on the "-" control on the map to "un-zoom" it a little bit. Is this possibile?

```
from folium import Map, Marker
from dash import html, Dash

def create_map(coordinates, output_file="map.html"):
    # Create a map centered at the first pair of coordinates
    #my_map = Map(location=coordinates[0], zoom_start=13)
    my_map = Map()

    # Add a marker for each pair of coordinates
    for coord in coordinates:
        Marker(location=coord).add_to(my_map)

        # Calculate the bounds of the markers
        sw = [min(coord[0] for coord in coordinates), min(coord[1] for coord in coordinates)]
        ne = [max(coord[0] for coord in coordinates), max(coord[1] for coord in coordinates)]

        # Fit the map to the bounds
        my_map.fit_bounds([sw, ne])

    # Save the map as an HTML file
    my_map.save(output_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Replace these with your desired list of coordinates
    coordinates = [
        [37.7749, -122.4194],
        [37.7899, -122.4062],
        [37.7531, -122.4470]
    ]
    create_map(coordinates)

    # Initialize the Dash app
    app = Dash(__name__)

    # Read the map HTML file
    with open("map.html", "r") as f:
        map_html = f.read()

    # Define the app layout
    app.layout = html.Div([
        html.H1("Interactive Map with Folium and Plotly Dash"),
        html.Iframe(srcDoc=map_html, width="100%", height="600px")
    ])

    # Run the Dash app
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: `my_map.fit_bounds([sw, ne], max_zoom=13)`

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed. Going back to documentation to see why I missed it. If you care to post it as a reply I'd be happy to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Thank you for the proposition ! It's good that it can help you, it's just a small change, I don't think I need to write an additional answer.

Comment: Heartfelt thanks!